# Standard logical equivalences to prove: $p \to \left(q \lor r \right) \Longleftrightarrow \left(p \land \lnot q\right) \to r$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So far I tried:
$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
p \to (q \vee r) 
&\Longleftrightarrow \lnot p \lor \left( q \lor r \right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left(\lnot p \lor q \right)\lor r \\
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\text{Implication Law}\\
&\text{Associative Law} \\
&\end{aligned}
$$

But having trouble getting to $\left(p \land \lnot q\right) \to r$
Any help would be much appreciated, Thank You in advance.

Comment: Your second line is incorrect. It should be $(\neg p \vee q) \vee r$.

Comment: then that would means that De Morgans law would not be used for the thirds step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
p \to (q \vee r) 
&\equiv \neg p \vee (q \vee r)\\
&\equiv (\neg p \vee q) \vee r \\
&\equiv (\neg p \vee \neg \neg q) \vee r \\
&\equiv \neg (p \wedge \neg q) \vee r \\
&\equiv (p \wedge \neg q) \to r
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\text{Conditional}\\
&\text{Associative} \\
&\text{Double Negation} \\
&\text{DeMorgan} \\
&\text{Conditional}
&\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I believe "Conditional" is the same as "Implication Law"?

Comment: Yeah, I should've put implication law. But yes, the law saying $A \to B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \vee B$.

Answer (score 0):

$p \rightarrow (q \lor r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Implication)

$p \rightarrow (\neg q \rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$(p \land \neg q) \rightarrow r$